# why the submenu opens a bit late after the first click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Both menu and sub menu have the same css features. Submenu opens when I hover the `Products` and `Campaigns` buttons. The submenu is opening but I wonder why the submenu opens a bit late after the first click but opens normally in the next clicks?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">    
    <title>Hemilia</title>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <a href="/"><img src="/static/images/logo.png"></a>
</center>
<div class="menu" onclick="myFunction()">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="menus">
  <div class="dropdown" style="display: none">
    <button class="drop-btn" onmouseenter="onMouseEnter('.products')" onmouseleave="onMouseLeave('.products')">Products</button>
    <button class="drop-btn" onmouseenter="onMouseEnter('.campaigns')" onmouseleave="onMouseLeave('.campaigns')">Campaigns</button>
    <button class="drop-btn">Contact</button>
    <button class="drop-btn">About</button>
  </div>
  <div class="submenu" style="display: none">
    <div class="products" style="display: none">
      <button class="products-btn">Food</button>
      <button class="products-btn" >Clothes</button>
      <button class="products-btn" >Accessories</button>
    </div>
    <div class="campaigns" style="display: none">
      <button class="campaigns-btn">New</button>
      <button class="campaigns-btn" >Old</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url('static/images/wallpaper.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    a:focus {
        outline: 0;
        outline-style: none;
    }
    .menu {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .menu div {
        width: 35px;
        height: 4px;
        background-color: black;
        margin-top: 10%;
        border-radius: 2px;
        border: 2px solid #62D7A3;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    .dropdown, .submenu {
        background-color: black;
        width: 150px;
        margin-top: 1.2%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #62D7A3;
        opacity: 0.5;
        float: left;
    }
    .drop-btn, .products-btn, .campaigns-btn {
        display: block;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-top: 1%;
        color: #62D7A3;
        background-color: black;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
    }
    .drop-btn:hover, .products-btn:hover, .campaigns-btn:hover {
        color: grey;
    }
</style>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0];
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    $(".dropdown").slideDown("fast");
  } else {
    $(".dropdown").slideUp("fast");
    $(".submenu").slideUp("fast");
  }
}

function onMouseEnter(x) {
  $(".submenu").slideDown("fast");
  if (x === ".products") {
    $(".campaigns").slideUp("fast");
  }
  else if (x == ".campaigns") {
    $(".products").slideUp("fast");
  }
  $(x).slideDown("fast");
}

function onMouseLeave(x) {
  $(".submenu").mouseleave(
    function() {
      $(".submenu").slideUp("fast");
    }
  )
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works on hover not clicks, and I don't see any delay... Edit; i see a bit of delay...

Comment: I think it's because you have `slideDown` running on both `.submenu` and one of its children at the same time when you first open the sub-menu. After the sub-menu is open, it's just the children animating.

Comment: Ok let me change.

Comment: Thank you Ouroborus. I replaced `$(".submenu").slideDown("fast");` with `$(".submenu").css({"display": "block"});`, and the problem is solved.